# Failing to sign jpackage exe installer

Tags: signtool, jpackage

I get 0x800700c1 sign tool error when trying to sign exe installer made by jpackage. It used to work fine in the past, though newish JDK 17 and JDK 21 create unsignable exe. MSI created with the same settings signs just fine. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The file is probably corrupted in some way. You could try signing with another tool such as [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/), if the operation fails you should get a more explicit error message.

(disclaimer: I'm the author of this project)